# Clock on ESP-12F gives wrong time

Tags: micropython, esp-12f

1. I connect the ESP-12F to the Linux machine on USB0 port.
2. From Linux console login into ESP-12F.

   ```
   $ picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b115200
   ```
3. Set the clock using MicroPython:

   ```
   >>> import utime
   >>> import machine
   >>> time=(2021, 11, 21, 23, 42, 0, 6, 325)
   >>> machine.RTC().datetime(time)
   >>> utime.localtime()
   (2021, 11, 22, 18, 0, 11, 0, 326)
   ```

Time changed and the day as well. ~19 hours was added to the time I wanted. What did I do wrong? I do not want to synchronize, just to set.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question.

> ...The documentation is wrong... Parameter 4 is the day of week..."

> The 8-tuple has the following format: (year, month, day, weekday,
> hours, minutes, seconds, sub-seconds)
>
> (0) year includes the century (for example 2020) 
> (1) month is 1-12 
> (2) mday is 1-31 or yday 1-365/366 
> (3) weekday is 0-6 for Mon-Sun ***Set to 0, being Auto Set by machine 
> (4) hour is 0-23 
> (5) minute is 0-59 
> (6) second is 0-59 
> (7) sub-seconds